# Extract table name and columns from SQL schema

Tags: regex

I need help to export table-name & columns from table schema (DDL) using regex.

```sql
CREATE TABLE todos (
  id          INTEGER NOT NULL,
  user_id     INTEGER NOT NULL,
  team_id     INTEGER NOT NULL,
  title       TEXT    NOT NULL DEFAULT "Hello World!",
  description TEXT    NOT NULL UNIQUE,

  UNIQUE (title),
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (team_id) REFERENCES teams (t_id)
       ON UPDATE RESTRICT
       ON DELETE RESTRICT
)
```

1. Table name

```
todos
```

2. Columns

```
id       // as group 1 (column name)
INTEGER  // as group 2 (column type)
NOT NULL // as group 3 (column nullable) empty if nothing
DEFAULT  // as group 4 (default value for example "Hello World")
UNIQUE   // as group 5 (column uniqueable) empty if nothing
```

- Note: **UNIQUE** can be also on table level same as `title` column.

3. Primary key

```
id // as group 1 (primary key)
```

- Table level: `PRIMARY\sKEY\s+\(([^\)]+)\)`
- Column level: check below answer.

4. Foreign keys:

```
// first
user_id // as group 1 (foreign key)
users   // as group 2 (reference table name)
id      // as group 3 (reference primary)

// second
team_id            // as group 1 (foreign key)
teams              // as group 2 (reference table name)
t_id               // as group 3 (reference primary)
ON UPDATE RESTRICT // as group 4
ON DELETE RESTRICT // as group 5
```

- I've found a simple regex in [github] (https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/6351#issuecomment-91064631) but not support `RESTRICT`

  ```
  /FOREIGN KEY\s+\(([^\)]+)\)\s+REFERENCES\s+([^\(^\s]+)\s*\(([^\)]+)\)/mi
  ```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Caution regarding regex is that i can be slow, depending on how complex search your , what regex-engine you are using and how much data you need to process. I found that splitting a string and checking for keywords was much quicker in C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Extract a table name:

```regex
CREATE\s+TABLE\s+([\w_]+)
```

2. Get column names:

```regex
\s+([\w_]+)[\s\w]+,
```

3. Get a primary key field:

```regex
\s*PRIMARY\s+KEY\s+\(([\w_]+)\)
```

4. Get foreign keys data:

```regex
\s*FOREIGN\s+KEY\s+\(([\w_]+)\)\s+REFERENCES\s+([\w_]+)\s+\(([\w_]+)\)
```

You can test it here (respectively):

1. https://regexr.com/59251
2. https://regexr.com/59254
3. https://regexr.com/5925a
4. https://regexr.com/594eb

Comment: Thanks @LlyaLysenko, that works great. unfortunately, I also need to **FOREIGN KEY**  (edited question)

Comment: anyway, I've found the **FOREIGN KEY** regex in github.. check the new edit above

Comment: I've added it also

Comment: Perfect @ilya-lysenko, but seems like my question is missing some points. (edited) 

Answer (score 1):

The Regex are returning results into a `named captured group`, you can find the name if you look here `(?'GREOUP-NAME'..myregex...)`. It makes it easier for you to reference them after a finished regex search, it will be easier to split them.

### FULL SEARCH

```regex
((?'COLUMN_NAME'(?<=^\s\s)([[:lower:]]\w+))|(?'PRIMARY_KEY'(?<=PRIMARY\sKEY\s\()(\w+))|(?'TABLE_NAME'(?<=\bTABLE\s)(\w+)))
```

---

### SPLIT SEARCH

**Get table name:**

```
(?'TABLE_NAME'(?<=\bTABLE\s)(\w+))
```

**Get primary key:**

```
(?'PRIMARY_KEY'(?<=PRIMARY\sKEY\s\()(\w+))
```

**Get column name:** This one is a little bit sloppy and will only capture columns that are lowercase. Since your text didn't have any tabs-characters. This was the best i could do but it's a bit risky.

```
(?'COLUMN_NAME'(?<=^\s\s)([[:lower:]]\w+))
```

You can run [them here, regex101,](https://regex101.com/) and try it out.

---

*Be aware that the regex is dependent on whatever regex-engine your are using. There are some shortcomings regarding standards, and some regex's might need to be translated to your engine. For ex. `lookbehind` is not supported on all engines.*

Comment: Thanks bro, that works like a charm but I'am using V8's engine so `lookbehind` is not supported.